# Not able to apply security patch on my magento website as well as on default magento

Tags: magento-1.9

We have a Magento website having version 1.9.1.0 (CE). As I got the update from Magento support, to apply security patch on your store to prevent from security threat. We have downloaded the secutiry patch "PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-07-07-09-03-34.sh".

We have uploaded this patch on my root folder of test environment and then applied. But we got the error for my following files and patch is not applying:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/Mage.php
checking file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
checking file downloader/Maged/.htaccess
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
checking file downloader/lib/.htaccess
checking file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
checking file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 33.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file downloader/template/login.phtml
checking file downloader/template/settings.phtml
checking file errors/processor.php
Done
```

I don't know whats the meaning of above messages so that i can fix the issues. I also tried the same thing on default Magento system having same version, but got the same error.

Can anyone share us that why I am getting error and how can I fix the same?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the previous patches installed? If not, you will need to install them before SUPEE-6285. This is likely what is causing the problem. Alternatively, you can upgrade to 1.9.2 which includes SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994 and SUPEE-6285.

There's a bit more detail here: http://community.magento.com/t5/News-Announcements/Critical-new-Magento-security-patch/m-p/10137#M15